# XML parsing failed at line 1, column 9: DTD is prohibited

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, https, olap-cube

I have configured HTTP access for SQL Analysis server as stated in below article,
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140(v=sql.105).aspx

Finally I have configured the msmdpump.dll for my SQL Analysis service, and i am trying to load the connection string in Excel, I got the "XML parsing failed at line 1, column 9 DTD is prohibited" exception.

web.config from 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OLAP' is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="true" />
        <authentication mode="Forms" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>

        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST"/>
        <add name="Allow" value="OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, Accept"/>       
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
        <handlers>
            <add name="OLAP" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\OLAP\msmdpump.dll" resourceType="File" preCondition="bitness64" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Application pool of security identity is 'NetworkService'. Is anything administrator privileges is restrict the connection or any settings missed out?

Comment: @levi, Yes. This issue resolved by proving role permission for current user.

Comment: @Pranath could you please put in the answer with a description?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my problem by doing below things,

To do that open the SQL Management Studio and connect to the analysis database. Go to the your database and right-click the Roles folder. Select new role, give it a name and set the level of access you want to provide through the XMLA HTTP Access.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I did two things that resolved it:

First, I removed "accessPolicy" from the "Web.Config" file so that the "handlers" was empty, previously file file contained the following code:

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
    ...
</handlers>
```

I also had(previous to the issue) changed the account of the main website OLAP was running under to a new service account. The OLAP application was still running under a separate system account on a seperate app pool. I changed the OLAP App pool to the new service account.

I still get a 500 internal error when visiting the DLL([not correct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492140.aspx)):

> https://.../olap/msmdpump.dll

But excel now connects to my cube without error.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the well-intentioned advice above, the fundamental source of the error is a "500 - Internal server error" coming from IIS. That's what you need to focus on.

Excel’s parser (MSOLAP) isn’t expecting the first line of the server error which contains a XHTML 1.0 Strict document type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
    ...
```